# Executing unix commands from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When I am running mysql in the terminal

I can do something like `\! python ~/run.py` to run the the file.

However when I copy this to php and do mysql_query it doesnt work.

Comment: I'd say you should do everything you can possibly do to make MySQL *not* execute shell commands :)

Comment: That's right You shouldn't be trying to do that. If you want to run a shell command from php use system(), exec() or the back-ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run any of the **\** prefix mysql commands in PHP's `mysql_query`.

Only valid SQL commands can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

The `\!` commands in the MySQL Console are provided by the Console itself, not by the MySQL server proper. In other words, these commands are not sent to the MySQL server, but they are passed to the shell from which the console was launched (e.g. bash). This is a convenience shortcut, but won't work with normal SQL commands.